# How to re-route certain request url to different server in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, azure

I have here an Angular 2 application which is certainly running on NodeJS but heres the catch, consider this ng application is in the main directory **www.angular2app.com** and I have 2 other sub modules which is totally not angular which is

**www.angular2app.com/blog** > WordPress App 1

**www.angular2app.com/events** > WordPress App 2

**www.angular2app.com/anythingelse** > Angular 2

Is there a way to handle this requests properly in **NodeJS**? WordPress 1 and WordPress 2 are totally different sites. There is no apache or nginx here because it's on running on **MS Azure**

Hope some evangelic could help me with this problem.

Thank you

Comment: Try http-proxy. See issue resolution about path https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy/issues/758

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use the solution similar with `Virtual Directory` in IIS configuration. Please consider the following test structure in Azure Web Apps.

For simple reference, my test project only contains a node.js and a php application.

The project's structure:

```
wwwroot/
    -nodejs/
        -server.js
        -web.config
    -php/
        -index.php
```

The `server.js` is a simple node.js server script:

```
var http = require("http");
var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  response.write("Hello World!");
  response.end();
}); 

server.listen(process.env.PORT ||1337);
console.log("Server is listening");
```

The `web.config` is a iisnode configuration file for starter nodejs application, you can find the content at https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Using-a-custom-web.config-for-Node-apps.

And the `index.php` script contents a test sentence `phpinfo()`.

When you browse `domain/nodejs`, the requests are against to the node.js application.

And when you browse `domain/php`, the requests are against to the PHP application.

Any further concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: We have tried this solution and gets an error http://imgur.com/k2qpEkU. I guess it is probably working but we lack some sort of configuration in the Azure server